# Play an animated GIF in python with tkinter while loading

Tags: python, tkinter, animated-gif

I'm trying to play a GIF and let it loop for 4 secs while loading a progress bar. I've tried so many combinations of solutions to no avail. Below is the closest I got. The loadingAnimation() function runs the progress bar well but I can't get the gif part together(M_95()). Ideally would love for the GIF to play in the middle of the screen at the same time the progress bar loads, then close the GIF window when it's finished.

```
import threading
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
frames = [PhotoImage(file='./myScripts/M-95.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(10)]

def M_95() :
    # Play GIF (file name = m95.gif) in a 320x320 tkinter window 
    # Play GIF concurrently with the loading animation below
    # Close tkinter window after play 
  
def loadingAnimation(process):
    while process.is_alive() :
        animation = ["[■□□□□□□□□□]","[■■□□□□□□□□]", "[■■■□□□□□□□]", "[■■■■□□□□□□]", "[■■■■■□□□□□]", "[■■■■■■□□□□]", "[■■■■■■■□□□]", "[■■■■■■■■□□]", "[■■■■■■■■■□]", "[■■■■■■■■■■]"]
        for i in range(len(animation)):
            sys.stdout.write("\r | Loading..." + animation[i % len(animation)])
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.4)

loading_process = threading.Thread(target = M_95)
loading_process.start()

loadingAnimation(loading_process) 
loading_process.join()
```

Comment: is your question simply how to play a `gif` in `tkinter` window? because that question has been answered here before and I am sure there are plenty of resources on how to do that, also how exactly did you try to do that?

Comment: You shouldn't call `tkinter` methods from threads other than the one where you created the `tk.Tk` window. Use `.after` scripts instead like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801)

Comment: @Matiis Yes but with a twist. I want the GIF to play in tkinter at the same time the animation bar is loading. I have seen several answers in relation to that but nothing specifically addresses playing GIFs in a coherent manner, just basic stick animations. The comments in the M_95 definition above suggests what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: *"I'm trying to play a GIF and let it loop for 4 secs while loading a progress bar."* But in your code, it seems like you want to animate the GIF one cycle only instead of 4 secs.  So which one do you want exactly: animate GIF one cycle or animate GIF up to 4 secs?

Comment: @TheLizzard thanks for the link. The first answer is pretty neat however I'm still stuck in the GIF part. Could you help with my suggestion above 

Comment: @acw1668 sorry for the confusion. One cycle of the GIF lasts for 4 secs...as well as the loading bar. So I'm trying to play one cycle of the GIF as the loading bar runs concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First using while loop and `time.sleep()` in the main thread of a tkinter application is not recommended because it will block tkinter `mainloop()` and then cause the GUI not responding.

Suggest to:

- use `.after()` to show the animated GIF because it is not safe to update tkinter widgets in a thread
- use thread on `loadingAnimation()` instead

```py
import threading
import tkinter
import sys
import time

root = tkinter.Tk()
frames = [tkinter.PhotoImage(file='./myScripts/M-95.gif', format='gif -index %i'%(i)) for i in range(10)]

def center_window(win):
    win.wait_visibility() # make sure the window is ready
    x = (win.winfo_screenwidth() - win.winfo_width()) // 2
    y = (win.winfo_screenheight() - win.winfo_height()) // 2
    win.geometry(f'+{x}+{y}')

def M_95(n=0, top=None, lbl=None):
    # Play GIF (file name = m95.gif) in a 320x320 tkinter window
    # Play GIF concurrently with the loading animation below
    # Close tkinter window after play
    global process_is_alive  # used in loadingAnimation()
    delay = 4000 // len(frames) # make one cycle of animation around 4 secs
    if n == 0:
        root.withdraw()
        top = tkinter.Toplevel()
        lbl = tkinter.Label(top, image=frames[0])
        lbl.pack()
        center_window(top)
        process_is_alive = True
    if n < len(frames)-1:
        lbl.config(image=frames[n])
        lbl.after(delay, M_95, n+1, top, lbl)
    else:
        top.destroy()
        root.deiconify()
        process_is_alive = False


def loadingAnimation():
    animation = ["[■□□□□□□□□□]","[■■□□□□□□□□]", "[■■■□□□□□□□]", "[■■■■□□□□□□]", "[■■■■■□□□□□]", "[■■■■■■□□□□]", "[■■■■■■■□□□]", "[■■■■■■■■□□]", "[■■■■■■■■■□]", "[■■■■■■■■■■]"]
    i = 0
    while process_is_alive:
        sys.stdout.write("\r | Loading..." + animation[i % len(animation)])
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.4)
        i += 1

M_95() # start GIF animation
threading.Thread(target=loadingAnimation).start()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Update: animate GIF more than one cycle in around 4 secs:

```py
def M_95(n=0, top=None, lbl=None):
    # Play GIF (file name = m95.gif) in a 320x320 tkinter window
    # Play GIF concurrently with the loading animation below
    # Close tkinter window after play
    global process_is_alive
    num_cycles = 2
    count = len(frames) * num_cycles
    delay = 4000 // count # make required cycles of animation in around 4 secs
    if n == 0:
        root.withdraw()
        top = tkinter.Toplevel()
        lbl = tkinter.Label(top, image=frames[0])
        lbl.pack()
        center_window(top)
        process_is_alive = True
        lbl.after(delay, M_95, n+1, top, lbl)
    elif n < count-1:
        lbl.config(image=frames[n%len(frames)])
        lbl.after(delay, M_95, n+1, top, lbl)
    else:
        top.destroy()
        root.destroy()
        process_is_alive = False
```

Comment: You're a genius man! Nice work! The only minor issue is that a blank tkinter window opens after the GIF window closes and the script won't proceed until I manually close it. Any idea what I need to do to fix that?

Comment: I found a soln. I just replaced ```root.deiconify( )``` with ```root.destroy```. Thanks again sir!

Comment: final question: How would you approach running 2 GIF cycles in 4 secs?

Comment: @BJonas88 Answer updated with animate GIF 2 cycles in 4 secs.